# identify incorrect preposition usage in a word document using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to identify incorrect or missing prepositions. Currently, exploring only "a" and "the".
(i) The first time a noun is used the preposition should be "a." Subsequent usages of the noun should use the "the" preposition. 
(ii) Identify all subsequent uses of the noun without "the" preposition. 
(iii) Identify incorrect or reuse of "a" after first introduction. 
(iv) Highlight these errors as the document is being typed.

I am trying to learn VBA and could not get started with this task.

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. If not - please say so. This is why I answer it like this: Find out how to iterate over all words in your text. Once there you can start to think about the rules stated in your task. Some phrases to look for in the documentation are Paragraphs, Range, Split, and For Each

Comment: How do you propose to identify nouns?

Comment: Not homework, not in school, not a paid programmer, if that's what you mean. Trying to eliminate some common errors in some documents.  This error a major flag in many documents and current fix is manual review. Was hoping not to use a parser for nouns and have a work around. Maybe just assume the first time "a" is used that the word following it is a noun. Similarly, if "the" is present, what follows is a noun and must have been introduced with "a" in the document. So, identifying the noun isn't a parsing problem?

Comment: Good Idea. Try and comeback with code.